# Texture mapping not working in Particle material in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a space warp particle effect with three js but ran on a problem. The particle created is cubical, but I want it to be spherical. I loaded a circle png and mapped it to the particle material but it doesn't work.

```js
function init() {

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
  });
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
  const app = document.getElementById("app");
  app.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // setup camera
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    60,
    innerWidth / innerHeight,
    1,
    1000
  );
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1);
  camera.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const starGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const starCount = 6000;
  const vertices = new window.Float32Array(starCount * 3);
  starGeo.setAttribute("position", new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  const starsArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < starCount * 3; i += 3) {
    vertices[i] = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
    vertices[i + 1] = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
    vertices[i + 2] = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      starsArr.push({
        velocity: 0,
        acceleration: 0.02,
      });
    }
  }

  starGeo.attributes.position.stars = starsArr;
 


// link to yellow circle 
 const starTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHU59FFoWzbzpl_37EPznha05psUWXZJqeXDK_57OXhRCuB6IYMamNujWbewVL4CAYuMM&usqp=CAU"); 
  
  // using white circle does nothing, gives blank screen, even while using local image
 /*  const starTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/white-circle-png-new-moon-phase-drawi-11563654400bdrw3yigxk.png");*/
  
  
  const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
   // size: 0.7,
     size: 5,
    map: starTexture,
     transparent: true,
  });

  const stars = new THREE.Points(starGeo, material);

  scene.add(stars);

  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
     camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  });

  
  
  animate();

  function update() {
    const position = starGeo.getAttribute("position");
    const { array } = position;

    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i += 3) {
      const _i = parseInt(i);
      const j = Math.floor((_i - 1) / 3);

      position.stars[j].velocity += position.stars[j].acceleration;
      array[i] -= position.stars[j].velocity;
      if (array[i] < -200) {
        array[i] = 200;
        position.stars[j].velocity = 0;
      }
    }

    stars.rotation.y += 0.01;
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
   // update();

    starGeo.getAttribute("position").needsUpdate = true;
  }
}

init();
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also have made codepen for this here > https://codepen.io/exxnnonymous/pen/rNJyYwx

Answer (score 0):

The image you are using has the mime type `image/jpeg`. So you can't use the texture as intended. Make sure to use PNG (which has an alpha channel).